# powershell & sqlplus script in for loop

Tags: powershell

So I am quite new to powershell and I have a Oracle sql scipt I want to run inside a powershell loop

Function to read a text file to read a list of servers.

```
$oracleServers     = "C:\Temp\oracle-servers.txt"

function Database-Servers
 {
   $servers = Get-Content $oracleServers
   Return($servers.Trim())
 }
```

Next I read from that list what Oracle Services are running

function Installed-Databases

```
$svr        = $args[0]
$runningDBs = " "

$runningDBs = Get-Service -Name "OracleService*" -ComputerName $svr | 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty name | Out-String | % {$_.replace("OracleService","")}  

Return($runningDBs)

 function ConnectString
 {
   $CString     = " " #$args[0]

   foreach ($server in Database-Servers) 
   {
    $runningDBs = Installed-Databases $server
    $rdblist    = $runningDBs -split '[\n]'
        foreach ( $rdb in $rdblist) 
             {
             if(!$rdb -eq " ")
              {
               $CString = ' system/$rdb@$server$tnsalias$rdb'
               &sqlplus $CString  $scriptsql | out-file  $outputfile
                 Write-Host $CString
                 Return($CString)
               }
             }
   }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I can't get the inner loop to execute sqlplus frommy dynamically made tns entry.  My $Cstring param looks fine when I echo it out.  It's seems to be joing the execution of sqlplus to my string